Optimizing office script automation for Sharepoint Excel
I have Excel file in Sharepoint.
Here is my office script that I saved in folder.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const ws = workbook.getWorksheet("2024");



// Get the ranges for the entire block E26:E32 and individual cells E26 to E32
    const ranges = ws.getRanges("E26:E32,E26,E27,E28,E29,E30,E31,E32").getAreas();



// The first range covers E26:E32 as a whole
    const blockRange = ranges[0];
    const values = blockRange.getValues(); // Get all values in E26:E32 as a 2D array



// Manually check each value and unhide/hide the next row based on the value
// values[0][0] corresponds to E26, values[1][0] corresponds to E27, and so on



// Check value in E26 and control visibility of row 27
    ranges[2].setRowHidden(values[0][0] === 0);



// Check value in E27 and control visibility of row 28
    ranges[3].setRowHidden(values[1][0] === 0);



// Check value in E28 and control visibility of row 29
    ranges[4].setRowHidden(values[2][0] === 0);



// Check value in E29 and control visibility of row 30
    ranges[5].setRowHidden(values[3][0] === 0);



// Check value in E30 and control visibility of row 31
    ranges[6].setRowHidden(values[4][0] === 0);



// Check value in E31 and control visibility of row 32
    ranges[7].setRowHidden(values[5][0] === 0);



}



I have power automate that watches changes in that excel file and executes that script, but it takes 8 seconds to run it.
The idea is to add new row any time I add entry to balance sheet, and to show or hide columns based on some other criteria in other worksheets.
Seems like reading takes a lot of time, it is not as fast as in vba script.
How can I optimize that script?

The function BalanceSheet(ws: ExcelScript.Worksheet) takes a worksheet object as the argument. However, BalanceSheet(workbook) pass a workbook object as the argument. Are you sure the script works well?

I changed the code. even this simple script takes 9 seconds to execute with power automate

where it takes 8 seconds for the condition if the file was changed, and 1 second for this simple script.
